# Should this question about docker-compose remain closed, or should it be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, close-reasons

This question ([docker-compose run existing container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754587/docker-compose-run-existing-container)) was closed as off topic:

> We don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow. You can edit the question so it’s on-topic for Stack Overflow.

The [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) states that questions regarding software development tools are on topic for the site.

My first instinct was to vote to reopen, but I thought I should ask first since some of the close voters are very experienced SO users.

Why was this question closed as off-topic?

Comment: It's borderline. It is marginally related to programming. The question asks about proper usage of docker, which is used in running applications in a container. The software to be run is already developed. By following this logic we should allow questions about any application. Where do we draw a line?

Answer (score 7):

I'm one of the people that voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52754587/docker-compose-run-existing-container). It was closed almost 15 months ago, so my memory of voting to close it is sketchy, at best. After looking at the question again, I've voted to reopen (and the question is reopened), although I wouldn't be surprised to find that the question is a duplicate (I haven't looked, yet).

Docker is a tool that's used at the system level to run applications in a isolated container. Its use is *not inherently* programming related. A large portion of its use is in system-level deployment of applications both in professional and non-professional environments. Such questions are appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), or other appropriate Stack Exchange site.

However, Docker is also used as a tool in programming environments, so a significant number of questions about it are on-topic for Stack Overflow. But, just the use of Docker doesn't make the question on-topic. To determine if the question is on-topic, we need to look at what each question is asking and the context in which Docker's being used and the question asked.

This specific question, boils down to: "what command line arguments should I use to execute `docker` to be able to repeatedly execute the command without needing to do anything else?" That's not really a programming question. But, in this specific instance the context in which it's being used by the question OP is very clearly a programming context. As such, I feel this question straddles both programming and system level tasks and could be on-topic here on Stack Overflow or on other Stack Exchange sites.

Overall, I think we got it wrong in closing this question. This specific question is about using "[software tools commonly used by programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" in a software development context, even if the question boils down to something that's not 100% "[unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

Comment: That "software tools" comment is used far too often to justify many questions. "My car has a computer I can hack so can I ask about engine timing?". That's a pretty big stretch I made but some use it quite often. The rest of your comment shows where a lot of confusion arises.

Comment: @Rob Yes, it is. IMO, it's taken too far on a regular basis. I'm usually of the opinion that the portion of the on-topic statement that is "[unique to software development](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" needs to be fulfilled too, at least to a large extent. I expect that was a significant portion of my originally voting to close (it's too long ago, so I can't say for sure). However, looking at the *this specific question*, the context is definitely programming related ("get access to a debugger (ipdb)"). On balance, I feel this question is sufficiently programming related to be on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the question is on-topic here, and should be reopened.

A vast amount of developers use container technologies in a daily bases during development and deployment, and to consider these tools off-topic would be a disservice to the community.

Lumping [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) and [docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-compose) questions to SU would not help anyone, since most technology experts are probably here and not there, since docker is not a general computing tool.

The question has been reopened, with one of the original close-voters even reversing their vote.

Comment: But wouldn't that open the door to FreeBSD jails which are similar if not the same?

Comment: @Rob is that a problem if a door opens?

Comment: I consider jails to be an operating system environment in the same way Docker is. It's not programming related.

Comment: @Rob so you would argue it is more devops like?

Comment: @rene I would..