# «When a question reaches 3 reopen votes, it is no longer closed» is that so?

Tags: discussion, support, help-center, vote-to-reopen

According to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

> When a question reaches 3 reopen votes, it is no longer closed, and
> new answers may be submitted.

At least three different users expressed interest in reopening [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63845591/5675325) ([that is subject to different opinions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401112/5675325) - some find it valuable in SO and others don't) which would match the condition expressed by the documentation (at least three reopen votes were given in that question). The problem is that the votes were in different moments.

This question intends to either readjust the text in the help-center to

> When a question reaches 3 reopen votes **(the votes need to be around the same time)**, it is no longer closed, and
> new answers may be submitted.

or to reopen the question.

Comment: I mean... the timeline shows the question went to the reopen queue twice. I don't think there was ever three reopen votes *at once* on this question.

Comment: @Nick they did cast the reopen votes.

Comment: The documentation is correct, there is only one reopen vote on that question

Comment: @AnnZen in this particular moment yes

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 In that case, the text is still not wrong, it says when it _reaches_ 3 reopen votes, not _receives_ 3 reopen votes, they have distinctly different meanings

Comment: @Nick reached at the same time or not?

Comment: Reopen votes can be added and removed all the time via retraction, aging away, moderators opening/reclosing, if a post gets a vote, and it is retracted then gets 2 more votes, it has _received_ 3 reopen votes but it has not _reached_ 3. So yes, it needs 3 reopen votes to be active on it at the same time, they can be spread out somewhat, they don't even have to be on the same day.

Comment: @Patrice right with the *at once*

Comment: I don't think it's really..... important as a change, but I can see how ppl can be tripped by this

Comment: Were you really confused by this? Or is this a "just in case" suggestion?

Comment: @yivi yes, after going through the help center to understand more about the reopen process.

Comment: i mean... a question can receive an infinite number of reopen votes, expecting a total of 3  or more at any given time to result in reopening is silly. If it's closed, reopened, and then closed again, it's closed with 3 reopen votes. Can we throw this under "semantics"?

Comment: Should we also clarify that if a question is closed, reopened, and closed again, the original three reopen votes no longer count? Same for close votes, I guess.

Comment: At this point, even if it gets 3 simultaneously active reopen votes, resulting in it being reopened, I think it's also going to need some un-delete votes. However, I do not think un-delete votes ages away, like reopen votes. I believe one can also not retract those.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The votes don't really have to be at the same time, although both close and reopen votes do age away. What is the case however is that votes only count if they haven't resulted in any action being taken. So

- Let's say a question gets 3 close votes, its state changes to closed. Those close votes have done their job and they have no further part to play.
- Now the question receives 3 reopen votes, the question is reopened and those reopen votes are now done.
- If the question is to be closed again it now needs another 3 close votes.

We can't have all the votes it ever received counting as we'd never have any questions reopened as they'd all instantly qualify for closure (and then reopening) in an infinite flip-flop.